# L2 regularizer in tensorflow v2

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

The following model is defined in TF1, I am trying to migrate it to TF2 without using compat API.

```py
# Define the tensorflow neural network
# 1. Input:
self.input_states = tf.placeholder(
        tf.float32, shape=[None, 4, board_height, board_width])
self.input_state = tf.transpose(self.input_states, [0, 2, 3, 1])
# 2. Common Networks Layers
self.conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=self.input_state,
                                filters=32, kernel_size=[3, 3],
                                padding="same", data_format="channels_last",
                                activation=tf.nn.relu)
self.conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=self.conv1, filters=64,
                                kernel_size=[3, 3], padding="same",
                                data_format="channels_last",
                                activation=tf.nn.relu)
self.conv3 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=self.conv2, filters=128,
                                kernel_size=[3, 3], padding="same",
                                data_format="channels_last",
                                activation=tf.nn.relu)
# 3-1 Action Networks
self.action_conv = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=self.conv3, filters=4,
                                        kernel_size=[1, 1], padding="same",
                                        data_format="channels_last",
                                        activation=tf.nn.relu)
# Flatten the tensor
self.action_conv_flat = tf.reshape(
        self.action_conv, [-1, 4 * board_height * board_width])
# 3-2 Full connected layer, the output is the log probability of moves
# on each slot on the board
self.action_fc = tf.layers.dense(inputs=self.action_conv_flat,
                                        units=board_height * board_width,
                                        activation=tf.nn.log_softmax)
# 4 Evaluation Networks
self.evaluation_conv = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=self.conv3, filters=2,
                                        kernel_size=[1, 1],
                                        padding="same",
                                        data_format="channels_last",
                                        activation=tf.nn.relu)
self.evaluation_conv_flat = tf.reshape(
        self.evaluation_conv, [-1, 2 * board_height * board_width])
self.evaluation_fc1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=self.evaluation_conv_flat,
                                        units=64, activation=tf.nn.relu)
# output the score of evaluation on current state
self.evaluation_fc2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=self.evaluation_fc1,
                                        units=1, activation=tf.nn.tanh)

# Define the Loss function
# 1. Label: the array containing if the game wins or not for each state
self.labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])
# 2. Predictions: the array containing the evaluation score of each state
# which is self.evaluation_fc2
# 3-1. Value Loss function
self.value_loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(self.labels,
                                                self.evaluation_fc2)
# 3-2. Policy Loss function
self.mcts_probs = tf.placeholder(
        tf.float32, shape=[None, board_height * board_width])
self.policy_loss = tf.negative(tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(self.mcts_probs, self.action_fc), 1)))
# 3-3. L2 penalty (regularization)
l2_penalty_beta = 1e-4
vars = tf.trainable_variables()
l2_penalty = l2_penalty_beta * tf.add_n(
        [tf.nn.l2_loss(v) for v in vars if 'bias' not in v.name.lower()])
# 3-4 Add up to be the Loss function
self.loss = self.value_loss + self.policy_loss + l2_penalty

# Define the optimizer we use for training
self.learning_rate = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(
        learning_rate=self.learning_rate).minimize(self.loss)
```

And here is my TF2 code

```py
l2_penalty_beta = 1e-4

# Define the tensorflow neural network
# 1. Input:
self.inputs = tf.keras.Input( shape=(4, board_height, board_width), dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
self.transposed_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Lambda( lambda x: tf.transpose(x, [0, 2, 3, 1]) )(self.inputs)

# 2. Common Networks Layers
self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D( name="conv1",
    filters=32,
    kernel_size=(3, 3),
    padding="same",
    data_format="channels_last",
    activation=tf.keras.activations.relu,
    kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(l2_penalty_beta))(self.transposed_inputs)

self.conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D( name="conv2", 
    filters=64, 
    kernel_size=(3, 3), 
    padding="same", 
    data_format="channels_last", 
    activation=tf.keras.activations.relu,
    kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(l2_penalty_beta))(self.conv1)

self.conv3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D( name="conv3",
    filters=128,
    kernel_size=(3, 3),
    padding="same",
    data_format="channels_last",
    activation=tf.keras.activations.relu,
    kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(l2_penalty_beta))(self.conv2)

# 3-1 Action Networks
self.action_conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D( name="action_conv",
    filters=4,
    kernel_size=(1, 1),
    padding="same",
    data_format="channels_last",
    activation=tf.keras.activations.relu,
    kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(l2_penalty_beta))(self.conv3)

# flatten tensor
self.action_conv_flat = tf.keras.layers.Reshape( (-1, 4 * board_height * board_width), name="action_conv_flat" )(self.action_conv)

# 3-2 Full connected layer, the output is the log probability of moves
# on each slot on the board
self.action_fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense( board_height * board_width,
    activation=tf.nn.log_softmax,
    name="action_fc",
    kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(l2_penalty_beta))(self.action_conv_flat)

# 4 Evaluation Networks
self.evaluation_conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D( name="evaluation_conv",
    filters=2,
    kernel_size=(1, 1),
    padding="same",
    data_format="channels_last",
    activation=tf.keras.activations.relu,
    kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(l2_penalty_beta))(self.conv3)

self.evaluation_conv_flat = tf.keras.layers.Reshape( (-1, 2 * board_height * board_width),
    name="evaluation_conv_flat" )(self.evaluation_conv)

self.evaluation_fc1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense( 64,
    activation=tf.keras.activations.relu,
    name="evaluation_fc1",
    kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(l2_penalty_beta))(self.evaluation_conv_flat)

self.evaluation_fc2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense( 1, 
    activation=tf.keras.activations.tanh,
    name="evaluation_fc2",
    kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(l2_penalty_beta))(self.evaluation_fc1)

self.outputs = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([self.action_fc, self.evaluation_fc2])

self.model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=self.inputs, outputs=self.outputs, name="policy_value_model")
self.model.summary()

def custom_loss(labels, predictions):
    expected_act_probs, expected_value = tf.split(labels, [self.board_height*self.board_width, -1], axis=2)
    pred_act_probs, pred_value = tf.split(predictions, [self.board_height*self.board_width, -1], axis=2)
    value_loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(expected_value[0], pred_value[0])
    policy_loss = tf.negative(tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(expected_act_probs, pred_act_probs), 1)))
    return value_loss + policy_loss

#print(tf.autograph.to_code(custom_loss))
self.model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
        loss=tf.function(custom_loss),
        metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Here is summary of this model.

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)           [(None, 4, 15, 15)]  0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 lambda (Lambda)                (None, 15, 15, 4)    0           ['input_1[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 conv1 (Conv2D)                 (None, 15, 15, 32)   1184        ['lambda[0][0]']                 
                                                                                                  
 conv2 (Conv2D)                 (None, 15, 15, 64)   18496       ['conv1[0][0]']                  
                                                                                                  
 conv3 (Conv2D)                 (None, 15, 15, 128)  73856       ['conv2[0][0]']                  
                                                                                                  
 evaluation_conv (Conv2D)       (None, 15, 15, 2)    258         ['conv3[0][0]']                  
                                                                                                  
 action_conv (Conv2D)           (None, 15, 15, 4)    516         ['conv3[0][0]']                  
                                                                                                  
 evaluation_conv_flat (Reshape)  (None, 1, 450)      0           ['evaluation_conv[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 action_conv_flat (Reshape)     (None, 1, 900)       0           ['action_conv[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 evaluation_fc1 (Dense)         (None, 1, 64)        28864       ['evaluation_conv_flat[0][0]']   
                                                                                                  
 action_fc (Dense)              (None, 1, 225)       202725      ['action_conv_flat[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 evaluation_fc2 (Dense)         (None, 1, 1)         65          ['evaluation_fc1[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 concatenate (Concatenate)      (None, 1, 226)       0           ['action_fc[0][0]',              
                                                                  'evaluation_fc2[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
```

As you can notice, the TF1 model outputs two tensors (`action_fc` and `evaluation_fc2`). And in TF2 model I added a concatenate layer in the last to combine them into a single tensor so that I can have a single loss function on them.

The loss function in TF1 model sum up three parts. The `l2_penalty` is the L2 lost of all weights in the model.

```py
l2_penalty_beta = 1e-4
vars = tf.trainable_variables()
l2_penalty = l2_penalty_beta * tf.add_n(
        [tf.nn.l2_loss(v) for v in vars if 'bias' not in v.name.lower()])

self.loss = self.value_loss + self.policy_loss + l2_penalty
```

In TF2 model, all trainable layers are added `kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(l2_penalty_beta)`. **Is that the same as TF1 model? Or do I make some mistake?**

The TF2 model will be executed in an environment without Python interpreter, that is to say the model will  be compiled into graph. I guess my  loss function has to be stateless -- it must not rely on any varialble out of the function scope.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the training logs from the fress TF2 model.  The `loss` looks abnormal. It is too small at the start.  The `loss` is greater than 4.0 in TF1 model.  Will the L2 regularizer be part of loss in TF2?

```
batch i:2, episode_len:113
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.7342 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - 18ms/epoch - 18ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.4714 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - 12ms/epoch - 12ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.1785 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - 14ms/epoch - 14ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.0829 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - 30ms/epoch - 30ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.0743 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - 13ms/epoch - 13ms/step
kl:0.00178,lr_multiplier:2.250,loss:[0.07430928945541382]
batch i:3, episode_len:92
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.0764 - accuracy: 1.0000 - 19ms/epoch - 19ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.0718 - accuracy: 1.0000 - 28ms/epoch - 28ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.0705 - accuracy: 1.0000 - 12ms/epoch - 12ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.0693 - accuracy: 1.0000 - 12ms/epoch - 12ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.0681 - accuracy: 1.0000 - 34ms/epoch - 34ms/step
kl:0.00068,lr_multiplier:3.375,loss:[0.06813239306211472]
batch i:4, episode_len:118
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.0676 - accuracy: 1.0000 - 16ms/epoch - 16ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.0665 - accuracy: 1.0000 - 12ms/epoch - 12ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.0654 - accuracy: 1.0000 - 12ms/epoch - 12ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.0643 - accuracy: 1.0000 - 15ms/epoch - 15ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.0631 - accuracy: 1.0000 - 11ms/epoch - 11ms/step
kl:0.00425,lr_multiplier:5.062,loss:[0.06307009607553482]
batch i:5, episode_len:84
1/1 - 0s - loss: 4.0628 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - 17ms/epoch - 17ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 4.0618 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - 12ms/epoch - 12ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 4.0606 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - 16ms/epoch - 16ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 4.0592 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - 11ms/epoch - 11ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 4.0577 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - 13ms/epoch - 13ms/step
kl:0.07804,lr_multiplier:3.375,loss:[4.057666778564453]
batch i:6, episode_len:96
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.0599 - accuracy: 1.0000 - 17ms/epoch - 17ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.0589 - accuracy: 1.0000 - 11ms/epoch - 11ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.0579 - accuracy: 1.0000 - 12ms/epoch - 12ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.0568 - accuracy: 1.0000 - 31ms/epoch - 31ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.0556 - accuracy: 1.0000 - 11ms/epoch - 11ms/step
kl:0.06898,lr_multiplier:2.250,loss:[0.055556993931531906]
batch i:7, episode_len:62
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.0577 - accuracy: 1.0000 - 28ms/epoch - 28ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.0569 - accuracy: 1.0000 - 11ms/epoch - 11ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.0559 - accuracy: 1.0000 - 14ms/epoch - 14ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.0549 - accuracy: 1.0000 - 16ms/epoch - 16ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.0538 - accuracy: 1.0000 - 19ms/epoch - 19ms/step
kl:0.03346,lr_multiplier:2.250,loss:[0.05379907414317131]
batch i:8, episode_len:118
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.0552 - accuracy: 1.0000 - 28ms/epoch - 28ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.0543 - accuracy: 1.0000 - 48ms/epoch - 48ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.0532 - accuracy: 1.0000 - 12ms/epoch - 12ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.0521 - accuracy: 1.0000 - 11ms/epoch - 11ms/step
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.0510 - accuracy: 1.0000 - 11ms/epoch - 11ms/step
kl:0.04336,lr_multiplier:1.500,loss:[0.051018256694078445]
```

Comment: if your concern is the `l2_penalty_beta` not being store in the serialization you should not worry, it's included in the serialization... also, you said _executed_, not trained, so idk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think that's the right way to add L2 regularization to the weights (but not the biases) in TF2

My only thought is that you don't *have* to concatenate the outputs tensors in TF2, you can define

```py
self.outputs = [self.action_fc, self.evaluation_fc2]
```

if that's easier. (Then also specify your losses as a length 2 list etc.).

Comment: but that means my loss function will be fired individually for each output

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean. If you pass a length 2 list of loss functions to model.compile(), the first loss will be applied to the first item in the list of outputs, and the second loss will be applied to the second item. TF2 is quite clever in dealing with this, but I'm not sure it's documented very clearly

Comment: If splitting into two loss functions, what is the proper loss weights ?  0.5 v.s. 0.5? and that is the same as the old model?

Comment: TF2 will sum the losses - I think that's also what your TF1 model is doing. I don't think TF2 reports regularization losses during training using model.fit().

Comment: There is in fact excellent documentation on using multiple outputs in TF2, and it is at https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#passing_data_to_multi-input_multi-output_models

Comment: Thanks @DavidHarris, I updated the code but encountered another issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73417734/loss-functions-for-multiple-output