# loss functions for multiple output

Tags: tensorflow2.0

As @david-haris figured out in [L2 regularizer in tensorflow v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73350571/l2-regularizer-in-tensorflow-v2), I shouldn't use a concatenate layer in the last to combine two outputs, I updated my model as below.  Full code is in the bottom.

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)           [(None, 4, 15, 15)]  0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 lambda (Lambda)                (None, 15, 15, 4)    0           ['input_1[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 conv1 (Conv2D)                 (None, 15, 15, 32)   1184        ['lambda[0][0]']                 
                                                                                                  
 conv2 (Conv2D)                 (None, 15, 15, 64)   18496       ['conv1[0][0]']                  
                                                                                                  
 conv3 (Conv2D)                 (None, 15, 15, 128)  73856       ['conv2[0][0]']                  
                                                                                                  
 evaluation_conv (Conv2D)       (None, 15, 15, 2)    258         ['conv3[0][0]']                  
                                                                                                  
 action_conv (Conv2D)           (None, 15, 15, 4)    516         ['conv3[0][0]']                  
                                                                                                  
 evaluation_conv_flat (Reshape)  (None, 1, 450)      0           ['evaluation_conv[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 action_conv_flat (Reshape)     (None, 1, 900)       0           ['action_conv[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 evaluation_fc1 (Dense)         (None, 1, 64)        28864       ['evaluation_conv_flat[0][0]']   
                                                                                                  
 action_fc (Dense)              (None, 1, 225)       202725      ['action_conv_flat[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 evaluation_fc2 (Dense)         (None, 1, 1)         65          ['evaluation_fc1[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
```

`model.fit` cannot be used in my case because this method is not allowed in a concrete function to be fired by C.

Hence I have to implement my own `train` method.

```py
        @tf.function
        def train(self, x, y):
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                predictions = self.model(x, training=True)  # Forward pass
                loss = self.model.compiled_loss(y, predictions) # <--- 
 
            gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.model.trainable_variables)
            self.model.optimizer.apply_gradients(
                zip(gradients, self.model.trainable_variables))
            result = {"loss": loss}
            return result
```

Thanks @DavidHaris. **Question updated**:

`model.compiled_loss` method accepts an optional parameter `regularization_losses`. There is a `kernel_regularizer` for each trainable layer.  I am not sure if I should set something in this parameter. Or `compiled_loss` internally computes partial loss from each `kernel_regularizer`?

Full source code:

```py
# basing on tensorflow v2.9
def create_model(board_width, board_height):

    class RenjuModel(tf.Module):
        def __init__(self):
            l2_penalty_beta = 1e-4

            # Define the tensorflow neural network
            # 1. Input:
            self.inputs = tf.keras.Input( shape=(4, board_height, board_width), dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
            self.transposed_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Lambda( lambda x: tf.transpose(x, [0, 2, 3, 1]) )(self.inputs)

            # 2. Common Networks Layers
            self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D( name="conv1",
                filters=32,
                kernel_size=(3, 3),
                padding="same",
                data_format="channels_last",
                activation=tf.keras.activations.relu,
                kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(l2_penalty_beta)
                )(self.transposed_inputs)

            self.conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D( name="conv2", 
                filters=64, 
                kernel_size=(3, 3), 
                padding="same", 
                data_format="channels_last", 
                activation=tf.keras.activations.relu,
                kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(l2_penalty_beta)
                )(self.conv1)

            self.conv3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D( name="conv3",
                filters=128,
                kernel_size=(3, 3),
                padding="same",
                data_format="channels_last",
                activation=tf.keras.activations.relu,
                kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(l2_penalty_beta)
                )(self.conv2)

            # 3-1 Action Networks
            self.action_conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D( name="action_conv",
                filters=4,
                kernel_size=(1, 1),
                padding="same",
                data_format="channels_last",
                activation=tf.keras.activations.relu,
                kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(l2_penalty_beta)
                )(self.conv3)

            # flatten tensor
            self.action_conv_flat = tf.keras.layers.Reshape( (-1, 4 * board_height * board_width), name="action_conv_flat" 
            )(self.action_conv)

            # 3-2 Full connected layer, the output is the log probability of moves
            # on each slot on the board
            self.action_fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense( board_height * board_width,
                activation=tf.nn.log_softmax,
                name="action_fc",
                kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(l2_penalty_beta)
                )(self.action_conv_flat)

            # 4 Evaluation Networks
            self.evaluation_conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D( name="evaluation_conv",
                filters=2,
                kernel_size=(1, 1),
                padding="same",
                data_format="channels_last",
                activation=tf.keras.activations.relu,
                kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(l2_penalty_beta))(self.conv3)

            self.evaluation_conv_flat = tf.keras.layers.Reshape( (-1, 2 * board_height * board_width),
                name="evaluation_conv_flat" 
                )(self.evaluation_conv)

            self.evaluation_fc1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense( 64,
                activation=tf.keras.activations.relu,
                name="evaluation_fc1",
                kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(l2_penalty_beta)
                )(self.evaluation_conv_flat)

            self.evaluation_fc2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense( 1, 
                activation=tf.keras.activations.tanh,
                name="evaluation_fc2",
                kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(l2_penalty_beta)
                )(self.evaluation_fc1)

            self.model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=self.inputs, outputs=[self.action_fc, self.evaluation_fc2], name="renju_model")

            self.model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                    loss=[self.action_loss, tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()],
                    metrics=['accuracy'])


        @tf.function(input_signature=[ tf.TensorSpec([None, board_height * board_width], tf.float32),
            tf.TensorSpec([None, None, board_height * board_width], tf.float32)
        ])
        def action_loss(self, labels, predictions):
            # labels are probabilities; predictions are logits
            return tf.negative(tf.reduce_mean(
                        tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(labels, predictions[0]), 1)))


            

        @tf.function
        def train(self, x, y):
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                predictions = self.model(x, training=True)  # Forward pass
                loss = self.model.compiled_loss(y, predictions)
 
            gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.model.trainable_variables)
            self.model.optimizer.apply_gradients(
                zip(gradients, self.model.trainable_variables))
            result = {"loss": loss}
            return result

        @tf.function(input_signature=[
            tf.TensorSpec([None, 4, board_height, board_width], tf.float32),
        ])
        def predict(self, x):
            return self.model(x)

        @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=[], dtype=tf.string)])
        def save(self, checkpoint_path):
            tensor_names = [weight.name for weight in self.model.weights]
            tensors_to_save = [weight.read_value() for weight in self.model.weights]
            tf.raw_ops.Save(
                filename=checkpoint_path, tensor_names=tensor_names,
                data=tensors_to_save, name='save')
            return {
                "checkpoint_path": checkpoint_path
            }

        @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=[], dtype=tf.string)])
        def restore(self, checkpoint_path):
            restored_tensors = {}
            for var in self.model.weights:
                restored = tf.raw_ops.Restore( file_pattern=checkpoint_path, tensor_name=var.name, dt=var.dtype, name='restore')
            var.assign(restored)
            restored_tensors[var.name] = restored
            return restored_tensors

    return RenjuModel()
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can help more here - subclassing tf.Module is an approach to writing tf code I'm not familiar with. I'm wondering about the way action_loss is defined as a method of class RenjuModel though. This will mean it will, as a function, expect 3 parameters (self, labels, predictions). Possibly try defining action_loss() as a standalone function, outside the scope of the class RenjuModel definition? ... (in edit)... hang on a second, I think you might have just forgotten to include 'self' as the first parameter in the definition of action_loss()!

Comment: @DavidHarris , Ah, you are right!  the loss function must bind to the class if set into `loss`

Comment: Will L2 loss be included in `compiled_loss` automatically? or I should set in `regularization_losses` parameter? I updated the question.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: It should include the losses generated by the kernel_regularizer= settings without you needing to do anything else. If you create a model (mdl = create_model(4,4), say), and look at mdl.model.losses you will see 8 numbers there already, corresponding to the losses from the 8 L2 regularizers in the model.

Comment: Having said that, I see the examples at https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/customizing_what_happens_in_fit always specify 'regularization_losses=self.losses', so that might be safer. Could you link me to the doc on the regularization_losses= option? I've not been able to find it.

Comment: Yep, I noticed `regularization_losses=self.losses` in examples as well. But seems it is not well-documented.  I am just afraid if I added `kernel_regularizer` and `regularization_losses=self.losses`, the loss will be doubled.

Comment: Thanks a lot. @DavidHarism May you please reply in answer? I cannot mark this question solved by comments,

Comment: Will do - and it should hopefully be a bit more coherent than the stream-of-consciousness in the comments above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the caveat that this is based on researching it rather than experience:

I think the call should be

```py
loss = self.model.compiled_loss(y, predictions, regularization_losses=self.model.losses)
```

Regularization losses (defined within layers) are stored in the 'losses' property of a model.

See:

1. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/customizing_what_happens_in_fit
2. Lines 948-949 of https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.9.0/keras/engine/training.py#L67-L3266, the Keras code that calls compiled_loss() to calculate losses within the Model fit() (via training_step()) method